# Windows 7 DNS Group Policy not applying

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

I've created a group policy in my GPO editor, under default domain policy -> Computer Configuration -> ADministrative Templates -> Network -> DNS Client -> DNS Servers, and put in my couple of DNS servers. I forced the update on my client with `gpupdate /force`, and then checked my results with `gpresult /z >c:\outfile.txt`. There, I see my configuration:

```
        GPO: Default Domain Policy
            KeyName:     Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DNSClient\NameServer
            Value:       49, 0, 48, 0, 46, 0, 50, 0, 51, 0, 52, 0, 46, 0, 50, 0, 48, 0, 49, 0, 46, 0, 49, 0, 48, 0, 32, 0, 49, 0, 48, 0, 46, 0, 50, 0, 51, 0, 51, 0, 46, 0, 56, 0, 54, 0, 46, 0, 49, 0, 49, 0, 0, 0
```

...I have looked at the value and it appears correct, looking up the decimal values in an ASCII table.

The problem is, the workstation does not seem to obey the group policy. I can do into the network card configuration and muck with the DNS, set it to whatever server I want, break it how I like.

I also set the DNS Suffix Search List and that looks correct, AND it's greyed out and I can't edit it.

How come my DNS server settings aren't sticking? ...If they were, I wouldn't be able to break my DNS but I can by hardcoding an incorrect IP address.

I have a Windows 7 workstation and a Windows Server 2003 Domain Controller (obsolete I know, but anyway the `gpresult` output looks fine to me).

Comment: It may have to do with how you are editing the gpo. Have you added the newer admx files for anything >2003 to sysvol? Are you editing the gpo using an up level gpmc? You should be using the gpmc from equal or greater the client level you want to control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That GPO setting is supported only for Windows XP Professional clients.

As an aside, why are you setting the DNS servers with Group Policy rather than assigning them via DHCP?

Comment: I inherited a rather funky, fragile, bizarre, and complicated network configuration. If I was King, I'd be using Microsoft DHCP (and will go there once my other fires are out). In the meantime, the GPO editor told me "Warning: The list of the DNS servers defined in this setting supercedes DNS servers configured locally and those configured using DHCP." Since that GPO setting is for Windows XP Pro clients only, it's all moot. Now I have to go put on my Cisco hat and modify my router... :-( . Thanks for the definitive (and short) answer.

Comment: Understood. Good luck in your adventure! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft recommends running their DHCP & DNS server on a server joined to your domain (such as your domain controller) to ensure clients get the correct configuration.

In a standard Windows Domain setup you have MS DHCP & MS DNS running. The DHCP server is configured to send the list of authoritative DNS servers to the client as part of the DHCP leasing process.

Manually setting DNS servers is usually only done when you're using a static IP configuration and that is a per computer setting so it can't be set by group policy.

You can find Microsoft's Documentation for their DHCP & DNS server here https://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc706993

Comment: `Windows Domains require the Microsoft DHCP & DNS server running on a computer joined to your domain (such as your domain controller) to function correctly. It cannot be running on your gateway (router/firewall).` - That is patently false.

Comment: I don't understand. If you're running a DNS server that doesn't talk with active directory then it can't update the DNS records when a domain computer IP changes. When I setup our 2008 R2 Domain Controller that was best practice per Microsoft's instructions: [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771732.aspx)

Comment: Whoops linked wrong page

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754493(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: AD doesn't require the DNS server to be joined to the domain. Any DNS server that supports SRV records and DDNS is supported for the AD DNS zone. You can use any DHCP Server implementation you like. The DHCP server need not be joined to the domain.

Comment: Would you recommend I remove that section of my answer then and leave the remainder?

Comment: Sure. Remove the part about it being required and suggest that using Windows DHCP in concert with Windows DNS is standard practice (but not required).

Comment: In any event, this answer is useful as it encourages me to wrap everything together. I have DHCP on Cisco, DNS and AD on Windows. I'm not happy with that setup.